# Variables not replaced in Twig template

Tags: php, twig, swiftmailer

I have this PHP code (just using [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) + [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)):

```
# Load Twig and swiftmailer
require_once('lib/SwiftMailer/swift_required.php');
require_once('lib/Twig/Autoloader.php');
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => 'cache',
));

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance(Swift_MailTransport::newInstance());

# Render twig template to a string
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('email.twig');
$body = $template->renderBlock('body', array('name' => $_POST["name"], 'letter' => $_POST["letter"]));

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setFrom("info@mydomain.com")
    ->setSubject("Hi, ".$_POST["name"]." blahblahblah")
    ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
    ->setTo($_POST["email"]);

# Send email, using PHP mail function
$retval = $mailer->send($message);
```

About my email.twig template:

- It contains {{ name }} and {{ letter }}
- It's contained between {% block body %} ... {% endblock %}
- It has a `<style>` node, with a few CSS styles.

**UPDATED: Link to template [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jorgeas80/reyesmagos/master/views/email.twig#)**

The email is sent properly, but with **2 problems**:

- **The second variable, *letter*, is not replaced. It's empty, even when *$_POST['letter']* is not empty**
- **Not all CSS styles are properly applied. I guess I can't use all the CSS properties in an email. Am I right?**

Any clues?

Comment: Can you post your template?  As far as CSS we'd have to see that as well. Keep in mind that each email client applies css differently. Inline css can help - check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've added a link to the template: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jorgeas80/reyesmagos/master/views/email.twig#

Comment: Have you tested this with hardcoded variables: `array('name' => 'foo', 'letter' => 'bar'));`?  I don't see anything weird off hand in your template.

Comment: Yes, also tested with hardcoded vars. Same problem. Just the name is replaced. Maybe it's something related with the CSS (paragraph has an associated CSS style). It's weird... But thanks, anyway!

Comment: If the problem were related to CSS, you would at least be able to see the variable value in the e-mail source code. Can you confirm that it is visible there?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Mmm... not sure if understanding. I'm going to change the template to just print the two variable values inside a simple div. No CSS at all. I'll update the post with it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and find a solution : that was due to some non-printable chars in the template. Not sure that it's the same for you, but maybe you should just try to rewrite the {{ letter }} part. (My french keyboard insert an invisible char with the combination of Alt-Gr + space).

[Object variable don't display in a twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981638/object-variable-dont-display-in-a-twig-template/34981968#34981968)